# Remote debugging nodejs app in Intellij with Docker - port already allocated

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, debugging, intellij-idea

I want to start debugging node.js app using Intellij and node.js interpreter running on Docker. While running the app works, when I try to debug I get the error:

> Error running 'index.js'
>             com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException:
>   {"message":"driver failed programming external connectivity on
>   endpoint focused_poincare
>   (a17137973880d1be7c6a74fc142184fdda31e0dec8ebd539b09d9dbe4cf70014):
>   Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:55578 failed: port is
>   already allocated"}

Remote interpreter was configured acccording to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-remote-node-interpreters.html). I have created a new Node.js Run/Debug configuration and entered the following data:
[image: node.js remote interpreter configuration].

**What might be the cause for debugging not working?**

I use:

- Intellij Idea Ultimate v. 2019.1.4 Preview
- Intellij NodeJS plugin v. 191.7479.1, NodeJS remote interpreter plugin v. 191.6014.8 and Docker plugin v. 191.7141.44
- Docker Desktop Community v. 2.0.0.3

EDIT: Adressing the comments:

Local debugging works. The file (index.js) that I am trying to  run consists only of `console.log('Hello world!')` so I don't spawn any child processes on my own. My host system has Windows 10 Pro as OS, so for checking the open ports on host system I used `netstat -an | find "55578"`, which returned nothing. Moreover, if I try to run docker manually from the command line, using `docker run -it -p 55578:55578 node`, everything runs and no error is given.

Also, each time I try remote debugging, the port number given by Intellij in an error message seems to be random high port number. I tried looking for open ports just after getting error message, <s>but never found one that is open with a number reported by Intellij</s> and those indeed appear in the output:[image]

My Run/Debug configuration:

[image]

My Docker configuration (I had to check "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" in Docker configuration to make Intellij and Docker play together):

[image]

EDIT: When I add `--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:55432` as "Node Parameters" in "Run/Debug Configurations" Intellij windows (per [this bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31709)) the container nad program start, but debugging seems to be no-op (e.g. the program does not stop on breakpoints).

Comment: Did you try with different port number?

Comment: @PrakashKrishna  far as I can tell, the port number is chosen by Intellij at random when I click the debug button. Where can I set it?

Comment: what is a result of `netstat | grep 55578`? also, does your app spawn child processes? can you debug it locally (using local interpreter)?

Comment: @lena I have edited my question and added the details you asked for.

Comment: please also provide screenshots of your node.js run configuration and docker configuration

Comment: see also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/04/quick-tour-of-webstorm-and-docker/

Comment: @lena Pictures added.

Comment: @lena I have also found that I was wrong when I wrote that the ports in question were free after I tried debugging - they are free prior to that, but after trying to start debugging, they appear in `netstat -ano` output (cf. image added to my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating to Intellij v. 2019.2 I was able to get the container debugging to work using the [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31709) already mentioned in my question.

I have added a parameter `--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:55432` to Node parameters option in Run/Debug configuration (see the picture below) and everything seems to be working, including the breakpoints.
[image]